# Prevent React from re-fetching data in parent component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, fetch

In my parent component, Dashboard.tsx, I have a child component, Expenses.tsx, that makes an API fetch call and then displays the data.  The parent component has a Router that allows you to navigate to different URL's in the parent component, which forces everything to re-render every time you navigate to a new path or render a new child component.  How can I make it so that this fetch call is only made one time?  I've tried using the useRef() hook but it re-initializes every time there is a re-render and I have the same problem.

Here is Dashboard.tsx:

```
export const Dashboard = () => {
  const d = new Date()
  const history = useHistory()
  const { user, setUser } = useAuth()
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState({
    expenseCategories: [],
    incomeCategories: []
  })
  
  const getCategories = async(user_id: number) => {
    await fetch(`/api/getCategories?user_id=${user_id}`)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => setCategories(result))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.info.user_id) {
      getCategories(user.info.user_id)
    }
  }, [])

  const dashboardItems = [
    {
      value: 'Add Expense',
      path: '/dashboard/addExpense'
    },
    {
      value: 'Add Income',
      path: '/dashboard/addIncome'
    },
    { 
      value: 'Logout',
      path: '/login',
      onClick : async() => {
        localStorage.clear()
        setUser({
          info: {
            user_id: null,
            email: null,
            username: null
          },
          token: null
        })
      },
      float: 'ml-auto'
    }
  ]

  return(
    <div>
      <DashboardNavbar items={dashboardItems}/>
      <div className="wrapper">
      <p>{`Hello, ${user.info.username}!`}</p>
      <DateAndTime />
      <Expenses date={d}/>
      <Income date={d}/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/dashboard/addExpense'>
          <AddItemForm user={user} type={'expenses'} categories={categories.expenseCategories} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/dashboard/addIncome'>
          <AddItemForm user={user} type={'income'} categories={categories.incomeCategories} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      <Logout />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And here is Expenses.tsx, where the fetch call is being made:

```
export const Expenses = (props: ExpensesProps) => {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  const { date } = props

  const { user } = useAuth()
  
  const m = date.getMonth() + 1
  const s = '0'.concat(m.toString())

  const [total, setTotal] = useState<number>(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTotalExpenses = async() => {
      await fetch(`/api/expenses?user_id=${user.info.user_id}&month=${s}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        if (result) {
          setTotal(parseFloat(result))
        } 
      })
      .then(result => {
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
    }

    if (user.info.user_id) {
      getTotalExpenses()
    }
  }, [])  

  return isLoading ? (
    <div>
      loading...
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      {`Your monthly expenses so far are: $${total}.`}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Each instance of `Expenses` is different, so it you want a new instance to access data from the previous instance then you need to store that data higher up in the chain.  You can store it in `Dashboard` and pass down props like `total` and `setTotal`.  Or you could use something like Redux which uses React Contexts.

Comment: Ah - that makes sense.  Okay - if I do store it in `Dashboard` though, won't it re-render each time `Dashboard` rerenders, whenever I navigate to a new route?  Then it will end up exhibiting the same behavior (re-fetching).

Comment: You would need to add some sort of conditional check so that you only fetch if you don’t already have data.

Comment: right - what I'm failing to understand is how or where to store that data after the initial fetch so that I don't fetch it again.  I'm having trouble getting useRef to do it - how would you recommend ?